Invoking HTTP based Firebase Cloud Functions running in an emulator from an Android emulator
I have a react-native app. I am trying to invoke a HTTP based Firebase Cloud Function running in emulator using firebase emulators:start --only functions from an Android emulator. I see that the Cloud Function is running at http://127.0.0.1:5001/dev-vg/us-central1/myapi. I am invoking this function using
    return fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:5001/dev-vg/us-central1/myapi/alarms/new`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + GlobalConfig.idToken
      }),
      body: {
        alarm
      }
    })

But this never reaches the emulated function. All the callable functions are invoked fine but not the HTTP based function created using onRequest.
What is needed such that these functions can be called successfully from the app?

127.0.0.1 in the android emulator doesn't refer to your local development machine - it refers to the emulator virtual device itself.  To reach the emulator's host machine, you're supposed to use 10.0.2.2 instead, as described in the documentation.

Thanks for pointing in the right direction. It works as expected now.
